# Union of lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $H=\mathbb{P}^2$, $X=V(y^2z-x^3)\subset H$ and  $p\in \mathbb{P}^3\setminus H$. Let $C$ be the union of all lines passing through $p$ and a point of $X$. I would like to find the equations defining $C$ to show that it is closed. How may I do this?

Comment: The _set_ of all lines is a subset of the Grassmannian. Do you mean the _set_ of all such lines, and you want equations in the coordinates of the Grassmannian? Or do you mean the _union_ of all such lines, and you want equations in the coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^3$?

Comment: I'm looking for the latter and edited the question accordingly. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Considering the analogous problem in $\mathbb A^3$ first might be easier for you.

Comment: If $p = [0:0:0:1]$ is the point $x=y=z=0$, then as a matter of fact an equation for $C$ is given by $y^2z-x^3$....! :-)